# How to use lodash to find and return an object from Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

My objects:

```
[
    {
        description: 'object1', id: 1
    },
    {
        description: 'object2', id: 2
    }
    {
        description: 'object3', id: 3
    }
    {
        description: 'object4', id: 4
    }
]
```

In my function below I'm passing in the description to find the matching ID:

```
function pluckSavedView(action, view) {
    console.log('action: ', action);
    console.log('pluckSavedView: ', view);  // view = 'object1'

    var savedViews = retrieveSavedViews();
    console.log('savedViews: ', savedViews);

    if (action === 'delete') {
        var delete_id = _.result(_.find(savedViews, function(description) {
            return description === view;
        }), 'id');

        console.log('delete_id: ', delete_id); // should be '1', but is undefined
    }
}
```

I'm trying to use lodash's find method: https://lodash.com/docs#find

However my variable `delete_id` is coming out undefined.

---

**Update** for people checking this question out, Ramda is a nice library to do the same thing lodash does, but in a more functional programming way :) 
http://ramdajs.com/0.21.0/docs/

Comment: Thanks for sharing about Ramada. I am just a newbie in the topic of functional programming.  Could you elaborate a bit more about why it is more functional programming than lodash.?Thanks.

Answer (score 191, accepted):

The argument passed to the callback is one of the elements of the array. The elements of your array are objects of the form `{description: ..., id: ...}`.

```
var delete_id = _.result(_.find(savedViews, function(obj) {
    return obj.description === view;
}), 'id');
```

Yet another alternative from the docs you linked to (lodash v3):

```
_.find(savedViews, 'description', view);
```

Lodash v4:

```
_.find(savedViews, ['description', view]);
```

Comment: Thanks! I just found out that this works too `var delete_id = _.result(_.find(savedViews, { 'description': view }), 'id');` Also 10 more mins...

Comment: The second solution is wrong, the predicate must be an array to use matchesProperty shorthand: it should be `_.find(savedViews, ['description', view])`

Comment: @FranciscoGuimaraes: Well, back in 2015, that's how lodash worked: https://lodash.com/docs/3.10.1#find

Answer (score 232):

lodash and ES5

```
var song = _.find(songs, {id:id});
```

lodash and ES6

```
let song = _.find(songs, {id});
```

docs at https://lodash.com/docs#find

Comment: When passing a variable in the find method, make sure to name the variable the same as the property name. In my case, i was looking for a country in my countryList. The country object has the properties _code_ and _name_. When i did `const countryName = "Netherlands"; let country = _.find(countryList, {countryName});` _undefined_ was returned. When i used `const name = "Netherlands"; let country = _.find(countryList, {name});` the correct object was returned.

Answer (score 43):

You can do this easily in vanilla JS:

Using [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```js
const savedViews = [{"description":"object1","id":1},{"description":"object2","id":2},{"description":"object3","id":3},{"description":"object4","id":4}];

const view = 'object2';

const delete_id = savedViews.find(obj => {
  return obj.description === view;
}).id;

console.log(delete_id);
```

Using [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) (original answer):

```js
const savedViews = [{"description":"object1","id":1},{"description":"object2","id":2},{"description":"object3","id":3},{"description":"object4","id":4}];

const view = 'object2';

const delete_id = savedViews.filter(function (el) {
  return el.description === view;
})[0].id;

console.log(delete_id);
```

Comment: True, but lodash seems so much cleaner, I don't have to use `[0]` this is the solution I'm going with `var delete_id = _.result(_.find(savedViews, { 'description': view }), 'id');` Thanks for the demo tho +1

Comment: Isn't it going to fail when you force [0] out an empty result? So +1 to @LeonGaban that Lodash should handle that by default.

Comment: @LeonGaban still you can use cleaner without lodash without [0] using ES6

`savedViews.find(el => el.description === view)`

Answer (score 15):

With the `find` method, your callback is going to be passed the value of each element, like:

```
{
    description: 'object1', id: 1
}
```

Thus, you want code like:

```
_.find(savedViews, function(o) {
        return o.description === view;
})
```

Answer (score 9):

**You don't need Lodash or Ramda or any other extra dependency.**

Just use the ES6 find() function in a functional way:

```
savedViews.find(el => el.description === view)
```

Sometimes you need to use 3rd-party libraries to get all the goodies that come with them. However, generally speaking, try avoiding dependencies **when you don't need them**. Dependencies can:

- bloat your bundled code size,
- you will have to keep them up to date,
- and they can introduce bugs or security risks

Answer (score 9):

Import `lodash` using

> $ npm i --save lodash

```
var _ = require('lodash'); 

var objArrayList = 
    [
         { name: "user1"},
         { name: "user2"}, 
         { name: "user2"}
    ];

var Obj = _.find(objArrayList, { name: "user2" });

// Obj ==> { name: "user2"}
```

Comment: add more details

Answer (score 8):

for this find the given Object in an Array, a basic usage example of _.find

```
const array = 
[
{
    description: 'object1', id: 1
},
{
    description: 'object2', id: 2
},
{
    description: 'object3', id: 3
},
{
    description: 'object4', id: 4
}
];
```

this would work well

```
q = _.find(array, {id:'4'}); // delete id

console.log(q); // {description: 'object4', id: 4}
```

_.find will help with returning an element in an array, rather than it’s index. So if you have an array of objects and you want to find a single object in the array by a certain key value pare _.find is the right tools for the job.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the following

```
import { find } from 'lodash'
```

Then to return the entire object (not only its key or value) from the list with the following:

```
let match = find(savedViews, { 'ID': 'id to match'});
```

Answer (score 6):

```
var delete_id = _(savedViews).where({ description : view }).get('0.id')
```

Answer (score 1):

Fetch id basing on name

```
 {
    "roles": [
     {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "admin",
     },
     {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "manager",
     }
    ]
    }



    fetchIdBasingOnRole() {
          const self = this;
          if (this.employee.roles) {
            var roleid = _.result(
              _.find(this.getRoles, function(obj) {
                return obj.name === self.employee.roles;
              }),
              "id"
            );
          }
          return roleid;
        },
```