# How can I return nested array with lodash?

Tags: javascript, json, lodash

I have some json and would like to return some nested objects, this is the json:

```
{
  "existingPackage": {
    "primaryBundle": {
      "id": "2031",
      "serviceId": "114297251",
      "name": "TV - Entertainment, Drama, Movies",
      "products": [
        {
          "name": "Entertainment",
          "id": "100",
          "price": 2600,
          "gifted": false
        },
        {
          "name": "Drama",
          "id": "104",
          "price": 2000,
          "gifted": false,
          "swappableProducts": [
            {
              "name": "Sport",
              "id": "107",
              "price": 2500,
              "gifted": false
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Movies",
          "id": "105",
          "price": 2000,
          "gifted": false,
          "swappableProducts": [
            {
              "name": "Sport",
              "id": "107",
              "price": 2500,
              "gifted": false
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The goal is to return only items from the productsarray which have the swappableProducts property and have a certain id.
So for example when I an productId = 105 then I would like to return:

```
{
          "name": "Movies",
          "id": "105",
          "price": 2000,
          "gifted": false,
          "swappableProducts": [
            {
              "name": "Sport",
              "id": "107",
              "price": 2500,
              "gifted": false
            }
          ]
        }
}
```

How can I return this with lodash?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use lodash to find and return an object from Array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31054021/how-to-use-lodash-to-find-and-return-an-object-from-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my approach:

```
_.filter(
  products,
  i => _.every([
    _.has(i, 'swappableProducts'),
    _.eq(_.result(i, 'id'), '105')
  ])
);
```

The idea is to pass both predicates to [every()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#every). The first uses [has()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#has) to check if the `swappableProducts` property exists. The second predicate combines [eq()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#eq) and [result()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#result) to check the `id` value.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
_.filter(data.existingPackage.primaryBundle.products, 
        function(o) { 
            return o.swappableProducts !== undefined && o.id==="105"; 
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that returns desired result

```js
const getProducts = obj => obj.existingPackage.primaryBundle.products;

const withSwappable = _.curry((myId, obj) => _.result(obj, 'swappableProducts[0].id', false) == myId)

function getProductsWithId(data, myId) {
  return _.filter(getProducts(data), withSwappable(myId))
}

const data = {
  "existingPackage": {
    "primaryBundle": {
      "id": "2031",
      "serviceId": "114297251",
      "name": "TV - Entertainment, Drama, Movies",
      "products": [{
          "name": "Entertainment",
          "id": "100",
          "price": 2600,
          "gifted": false
        },
        {
          "name": "Drama",
          "id": "104",
          "price": 2000,
          "gifted": false,
          "swappableProducts": [{
            "name": "Sport",
            "id": "107",
            "price": 2500,
            "gifted": false
          }]
        },
        {
          "name": "Movies",
          "id": "105",
          "price": 2000,
          "gifted": false,
          "swappableProducts": [{
            "name": "Sport",
            "id": "107",
            "price": 2500,
            "gifted": false
          }]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}


console.log(getProductsWithId(data, "107"));
console.log(getProductsWithId(data, "100"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```