# How to add a new element at end of the JSON array in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

I need some help to add a new element at end of the JSON array in nodejs

**Sample JSON Array**

```
[{
  "subject": "physics",
  "student_id": "2569",
  "values": "0.152,0.228,0.218"
}, {
  "subject": "maths",
  "student_id": "1236",
  "values": "0.146,0.22,0.212"
}, {
  "subject": "chemistry",
  "student_id": "4569",
  "values": "0.159,0.234,0.224"
}, {
  "subject": "physics",
  "student_id": "1478",
  "values": "0.16,0.235,0.225"
}]
```

**Expected Result should be**

```
[{
  "subject": "physics",
  "student_id": "2569",
  "values": "0.152,0.228,0.218"
}, {
  "subject": "maths",
  "student_id": "1236",
  "values": "0.146,0.22,0.212"
}, {
  "subject": "chemistry",
  "student_id": "4569",
  "values": "0.159,0.234,0.224"
}, {
  "subject": "physics",
  "student_id": "1478",
  "values": "0.16,0.235,0.225"
}, 
lastSyncTime: 1550467657366]
```

Please provide me with a simple solution.

Comment: That isn't a JSON array

Comment: U can't add an object like that to an array. use array.push({lastSyncTime:155})

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding a new array element to a JSON object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18884840/adding-a-new-array-element-to-a-json-object)

Comment: The simple solution in three simple steps: 1. parse the JSON, get an array; 2. push the new element at the end of the array; 3. generate a new JSON using the updated array. Your expected result is not a valid JSON. An array cannot contain named properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it with `javaScript`

```
var myArray = [{
  "subject": "physics",
  "student_id": "2569",
  "values": "0.152,0.228,0.218"
}, {
  "subject": "maths",
  "student_id": "1236",
  "values": "0.146,0.22,0.212"
}, {
  "subject": "chemistry",
  "student_id": "4569",
  "values": "0.159,0.234,0.224"
}, {
  "subject": "physics",
  "student_id": "1478",
  "values": "0.16,0.235,0.225"
}];

myArray.push({lastSyncTime: 1550467657366});

console.log(myArray);
```

And the result will be

```
[{
  "subject": "physics",
  "student_id": "2569",
  "values": "0.152,0.228,0.218"
}, {
  "subject": "maths",
  "student_id": "1236",
  "values": "0.146,0.22,0.212"
}, {
  "subject": "chemistry",
  "student_id": "4569",
  "values": "0.159,0.234,0.224"
}, {
  "subject": "physics",
  "student_id": "1478",
  "values": "0.16,0.235,0.225"
}, 
{lastSyncTime: 1550467657366}];
```

You can also get the last item using

```
var lastSyncTime = myArray[myArray.length - 1].lastSyncTime;
console.log(lastSyncTime); // That is: 1550467657366
```

---

Or if you want to find an object in a list using `lodash`, check the link below

[How to use lodash to find and return an object from Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31054021/how-to-use-lodash-to-find-and-return-an-object-from-array)